# Why do I get number 320.04 printed to the console in the below code?

Tags: java, return, system.out

I read the below code a lot of times and I cannot figure out why I get the 320.04 on the console. Can someone kindly help me figure out?

```
package com.heshanshivantha;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(126);
    }

    public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(double feet, double inches) {
        if (feet >= 0 && inches >= 0 && inches <= 12) {
            System.out.println(feet * 12 * 2.54 + inches * 2.54);
            double centimeters = feet * 12 * 2.54 + inches * 2.54;
            System.out.println(feet + " feet " + inches + " inches = " + centimeters + " cm");
            return centimeters;
        } return -1;
    }

   public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(double inches) {
        if (inches >= 0) {
            int feet =(int) (inches / 12);
            int remainingInches =(int) (inches % 12);
            System.out.println(inches + " inches is equal to " + feet + " feet and " + remainingInches + " inches");
            return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(feet, remainingInches);
        } return -1;
   }

}
```

126.0 inches is equal to 10 feet and 6 inches
320.04
10.0 feet 6.0 inches = 320.04 cm

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I am sorry my outputs have not seperated by lines..... 320.04 is the issue.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58795610/edit) your post?

Comment: `System.out.println(10 * 12 * 2.54 + 6 * 2.54);`

Comment: `System.out.println((10 * 12 * 2.54) + (6 * 2.54));`

Comment: what don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the first line after the if condition.
Remove `System.out.println(feet * 12 * 2.54 + inches * 2.54);` and you are done.